# emacs auctex: can one auto-fill section labels?

Tags: emacs, latex, auctex

I am currently using emacs and auctex to author my latex documents. This is, of course, fantastic. However, I would like to have emacs and/or auctex auto-fill the section label when using `C-c C-e` to make a new header. It should end up looking like this:

```
\section{This is a section title}
\label{sec:this-is-a-section-title}
```

with the label for the header the same as the title, but with no spaces. I don't know lisp or elisp, and I'd have no idea where to start. If anyone could help that would be great!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use RefTeX then `C-c (` will do what you want (giving you the opportunity to change the label if you wish).  Also `C-c )` will insert `\ref{...}`, popping up a buffer to choose which label to use.  It also does other stuff including working with bibliographies.  You should definitely look into it.

I think it's now part of the AUCTeX distribution so that all you should have to do is add

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (function turn-on-reftex))
(setq reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX t)
```

to your .emacs.

Comment: that is awesome. Thanks! I had no idea where to start looking for this.